# Access SQL Matching Join then Like Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Good Afternoon,

Is is possible in MS Access SQL to firstly try a matching left join and if there is no match then to a like/contains join?

Currently my like join looks like this

```
SELECT 
[tbl_Area_lkup].[Area], 
[tbl_Area_lkup].[Sub Area], 
[tbl_Area_lkup].[PageTrimmed] AS [Page lkup], 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.PageTrimmed AS [Trimmed Page], 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Page AS Page, 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Date, IIf([tbl_Medium_lkup].[mediumgrp] Is Null,"CHECK",[tbl_Medium_lkup].[mediumgrp]) AS Medium, 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Hostname, 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Users, 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Sessions, 
qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Pageviews


FROM (qry_AdviserPages_Step1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Area_lkup ON [qry_AdviserPages_Step1].[PageTrimmed] Like '*' & [tbl_Area_lkup].[PageTrimmed] & '*') 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Medium_lkup ON qry_AdviserPages_Step1.Medium = tbl_Medium_lkup.Medium

ORDER BY 2;
```

What I would like to do is an = join on the same Columns but if there is no match then to carry out the above join.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the SQL Statement? I feel the rest of the statement will help the context.

Comment: Updated. There is an extra join in there but that is for something else and that works fine.

Comment: I *think* you can try performing the join with the = first and then if nothing is found, use the join with the like after the join with the =.  Essentially, have two identical joins with one using = the other using like.  However, by doing this, it would use both joins, not one or the other. I'm not sure if one would cancel the other out. Potential solution?

Comment: @TSQL_Newbie Can you post some sample table rows to illustrate the results you want?

Comment: Bit hard to post due to the content. Basically it's web data from Google Analytics, I have the urls that contain the main part of the URL plus some with lots of parameters tagged on the end. I have a table of min URLs normalised with hostname removed e.g. www.shop.com/clothes/t-shirts would be /clothes/t-shirts. I have categorised them in the table so /clothes would be Clothes and /clothes/t-shirts sub area would be T-Shirts. I want as the URLs are not direct matches I need to do some sort of LIKE join, but /clothes would class /clothes/t-shirt as Clothes not T-Shirt. If that makes sense.

Comment: @TSQL_Newbie So does `qry_Adviser_Step1` have the URLs?  And `tbl_Area_lkup` has...keywords?  Or does it have URLs too?  Just posting a few rows (just the relevant columns) of the tables would go a long way towards understanding the results you're trying to get.